# Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1cd595b2c) in swift

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

I have a swift project. App is crashing when I tap on button.

```
func shareRide() {

          if let currentLocation  = currentLocation.value {

          let format = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:\(currentLocation.latitude),\ 
                       (currentLocation.longitude)"

          let  message = "\(AppName) :- \(String.removeNil(User.main.firstName)) \. 
                         (String.removeNil(User.main.lastName)) \. 
                         (Constants.string.wouldLikeToShare) \(format)"


          self.share(items: [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Splash_icon"), message])   *Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1cd595b2c)*

    }
}


func share(items : [Any]) {

    let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityController.excludedActivityTypes = [.airDrop]

    if let popoverController = activityController.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2, width: 0, height: 0)
        popoverController.sourceView = self.view
        popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)
    }
    self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

shareRide() is the method that calling when tap the button.

[This is a screenshot of my current bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPdWd.png)

Thanks, Looking forward for your answers!

Comment: In shareRide() method, format and message are not nil.

Comment: resource with "Splash_icon" also not nil? Have you checked?

Comment: Sorry, not yet, I will check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that `format` and `message` are not `nil`, then your image literal (Splash_icon) is probably `nil`.

Try removing it temporarily to verify this.

Comment: Glad to be of help, @S.kingstar! Please vote up the answer if it helped solve your problem.